# Symfony - Get Entity Repository with multiple ID's

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that has multiple keys, how would I go about finding the proper object based on multiple ids?

```
$product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little confusing what you're asking here. It sounds as though you have an entity with a compound key (primary key relates to multiple columns) and want to find it based on it's primary key values, yes?

If so, the `find` method will require an array containing values for each of the fields that make up the key:

```
$product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->find(array(
    'key1' => 'value1', 
    'key2' => 'value2'
));
```

Alternatively, you could use `findOneBy` method. This would be useful for when the combination of the provided fields are not unique as you're able to provide a second argument to define the ordering.

```
$product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->findOneBy(array(
    'key1' => 'value1', 
    'key2' => 'value2'
), array('updated_at' => 'DESC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

```
$product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->findBy(
    array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2'=>'value2')
);
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know if I should just use `findBy()` or if there was a specific method for that. thanks.

Comment: Careful, this will return an array of Products even if only one matches the criteria.